# Best Practice: How to draw a Countdown within a Service

Tags: android, service

i´m new to Android programming and I have a Question.

I have a Countdown that will count down from 60 to zero when i am touching the screen.
I want now that this Countdown will survive the Activity lifecycling even when onDestroy is called. So I need a Service for that.

Wenn the countdown is finished a notification will be send. But if the user want to open the App again before the countdown in the Service is finished, no notification should be sended and the service has to be stopped.

What is the best practice to implement those features? What is here the way to go?

Thank you very much for answers!

My approach is that I have a class with the countdown methods and the service

//Countdownclass
TimerClass.java

```
public class TimerClass {
private static final String TAG = "MyLog";
private static final long TIMERINTERVAL = 1000;
//Eigenschaften --------------------------------------------------------------------
private boolean isActiv = false;
private Paint paint;
private long timerTime;
private double actualTime;
private int x;
private int y;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private String timeString;

//Konstruktor --------------------------------------------------------------------
public TimerClass(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    paint.setTextSize(70);
}

public TimerClass() {

}

//Methoden --------------------------------------------------------------------
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(isActiv) {
        canvas.drawText(timeString, x, y, paint);
    }
}

public void createTimer(long timerTime) {
    this.timerTime = timerTime;
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timerTime, TIMERINTERVAL) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            actualTime = (double) millisUntilFinished / TIMERINTERVAL;
            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
            nf.format(actualTime);

            if(actualTime < 10) {
                new DecimalFormat();
                timeString = "0:0" + nf.format(actualTime  - 1);
            } else {
                timeString = "0:" + nf.format(actualTime  - 1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            isActiv = false;
        }
    };

}

public void timerStart() {
    countDownTimer.start();
    isActiv = true;
}

public void timerStop() {
    if(isActiv) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    isActiv = false;

}

public boolean isActiv() {
    return isActiv;
}

public void setActiv(boolean isActiv) {
    this.isActiv = isActiv;
}

public double getActualTime() {
    return actualTime;
}

public void setActualTime(double actualTime) {
    this.actualTime = actualTime;
}
```

And my Service:

```
public class TimerService extends Service {

//class with the countdowntimer
private TimerClass timerClass;
private long startTime;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    timerClass = new TimerClass();
    startTime = (long) timerClass.getActualTime();
    timerClass.createTimer(startTime);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    timerClass.timerStop();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    timerClass.timerStart();        
    if(timerClass.getActualTime() <= 0) {
        // send the notification
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

I wanted to start the Service in my mainActivies onPause method and stop it when onResume is called. But i´ve have tried it many times and failed.. so i have no code for my service in my activity.

( Sorry for my broken english :(  )

Comment: The best practice is what you just described. Share the code you have to keep guiding you in the right direction.

Comment: Here is my approach, but i think now i will combine the countdown class and the service. So the service will be started every time even when the app is still active?  Can I do that? Or is my previous description better?

Comment: Why stopping the service in `onResume()` has failed? This seems to be a good approach.